# SharePoint showing different time zone

Tags: 2013, timezone, sql-server-2012

I have created a SharePoint application which has a specific time zone.
The Windows server where SQL Server and SharePoint are installed are using same time zone.

When I create a new item in list in SharePoint it shows some different time zone time. You know the time it shows under "Modified"

I don't know why this is happening. If I query current date and time in SQL Server then it shows correct time zone but in SharePoint it is showing different times.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is the time zone set in SharePoint Central Administration?

Go to the following link and see if the time zone matches what you expect:

```
http://<CentralAdminUrl>/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx
```

Also check the regional settings for your Site Collection to see if the correct timezone is set.

Comment: That's strange. I set CA Application timezone to the same as my server. But when I went to regional settings page, the timezone was of different but the hours were in the same range. For e.g. if my timezone was +5 City1 then in regional settings it was +5 City2. Anyway I have changed it to +5 City2 and now I will check if it is working.

Comment: No this change didn't solve the problem. I created a new item in list to test and it said "Create at 11/4/2013 3:03AM" when here it's actually 2:04PM

Comment: Ok I found out that I actually had to go to Regional Settings of my site collection where the time zone was wrong.

Comment: Cool. I have updated my answer to check for the Site Collection regional settings too.