# SharePoint time differs from the time shown and time fetched using powershell scripts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I deleted a sub site at `7/13/2015 10:39 PM` as per the server system time. But the entries in the recycle bin of the particular site collection shows `7/14/2015 10:49 AM` which is ahead of the original event time. Also, one more thing which confuses me more is, when I see the recycle bin items data for that particular site collection using powershell script, deleted time mentioned is `7/14/2015 5:19:10 AM`. As per the below post,

[SharePoint showing different time zone](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/sharepoint-showing-different-time-zone)

I checked the regional settings of central administration and as well as the site collections regional settings for the correct time zone, still no use. Can somebody help me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a file regardless of what time zone you are in SharePoint server stores it into the SQL database using the Co-ordinated Universal Time (UTC) time zone.

Keep in mind SharePoint Manager uses the SharePoint API to pull all meta data. SharePoint Meta data is filtered, and set to SharePoint server settings. In the raw SQL content database we can verify that the file is stored in UTC time zone regardless of what ever time zones any server via this Microsoft article 2.2.7.3 AllUserData Table.

The implication here is that regardless of which time zone the file is uploaded the time zone data is reset and stored in UTC.

You can change the settings

- Web App Level
- Site collection level
- User level.

read this blog for more info: http://www.techgrowingpains.com/2012/05/sharepoint-time-zone-confusion-2/